# Thorn Whip, polearm mastery and attack of opportunity

Tags: dnd-5e, opportunity-attack, attack

What about this scenario: I pull the monster towards me with thorn whip BUT I have the polearm mastery that says "While you are wielding a glaive, halberd, pike, or quarterstaff, other creatures provoke an opportunity attack from you when they enter the reach you have with that weapon."

What happens then? Can I have an attack of opportunity? Or the general rule "You also don’t provoke an opportunity attack when you teleport or when someone or something moves you without using your movement, action, or reaction" prevents my plan from happening?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing specific in this maneuver that allows you to contradict the general. There are numerous instances of spells and abilities that allow you control the movement of others. None of them to my knowledge allow you to make an opportunity attack on the target.

From the PHB section on Opportunity Attacks (PHB 195):

> You also don‘t provoke an opportunity attack when you teleport or when
>   someone or something moves you without using your movement, action, or
>   reaction. For example, you don’t provoke an opportunity attack if an
>   explosion hurls you out of a foe’s reach or if gravity causes you to
>   fall past an enemy.

In the absence of specific wording allowing you to do so, no  opportunity attack is possible due to enforced or uncontrolled movement.

Comment: Thank you.
My GM appears to agree with this.
But it doesnt make any sense to me... if I willingly and cautiously enter an area of danger I will be hit, but if something pushes me by surprise and I am not ready or expecting it at all then it's fine, i'm safe? o.O

Comment: Game balance is a large factor in the ruling (a lot of quite broken combos arise without it), but the way I always made it make sense in my mind is that uncontrolled movement is generally fast and hard to read.  If someone is trying to move in as a controlled manner or a wild charge you can read their movements and act accordingly, but if they just got launched/pulled/thrown/...etc either their movements aren't predictable enough for it to be safe to try to hit them as there's a good chance your weapon would get caught on them somehow and ripped out of your grasp or they can focus on avoiding.